# PHP Fatal error : Cannot throw objects that do not implement Throwable

Tags: php, exception, throw

I am getting an error

> *PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot throw objects that do not implement Throwable*

I am trying to throw the exception

```
if ($err){ 
    throw new ShopException($err, $errno);
}
```

and the exception class for handling

```
class ShopException{
    protected $error;
        protected $errno;
    function __construct($error,$errno)
        {
            $this->error= $error;
            $this->errno= $errno;


        }
        function geterror() { return $this->error; }

 }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You need `shopException extends Exception`.

Comment: @musicliftsme thanks,  when add extends Exception , page doesn't work and i am getting error this class Exception not found.

Answer (score 0):

Please read about exceptions hierarchy - https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php
As error says your class ShopException needs to implement Throwable interface.
You can also inherit from one of standard exception classes that implements Throwable.
If you use namespaces you have to add backslash "\" before exception class name.

```
class ShopException extends \Exception { ...}
```